# Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Tags: java, java-ee, java-8, glassfish

estoy tratando de realizar un CRUD con mysql, pero mi problema es a la hora de relizar la conexion a la base de datos aqui el trozo donde intento ejecutar:

```
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/registro";
    String userName = "adrian";
    String password = "****";
    
    try{
        
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        set = con.createStatement();
        
        System.out.println("Conexion exitosa");
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Conexion no exitosa" + e.getMessage());
        System.out.println(e.getStackTrace());
    }
```

El salida del error es el siguiente:

```
Conexion no exitosaCannot open file:/home/addrian/GlassFish_Server1/glassfish/domains/crud-mysql/config/keystore.jks [Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect]
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Debes de manejar **useSSL=false**

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/registro?useSSL=false
```

Revisa esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586401/glassfish-keystore-error-after-adding-mysql-connector/52129961)